# How to format weekdays in a date in angular-google-chart.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

I went through the documentation given [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat) for date format.

It says "EE or EEE Produce Tu or Tues". I tried this

> format: "dd \n EE \n MMM"

date and month are fine but it produces "Tue" as a result. I want the result to be "Tu" i.e. only the first two characters of any week day.

Can anybody help me? Or suggest some method for achieving this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no EE in the filters and in DateFormatter of the Google Chart API, which inherited from angular js filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

But you can trim the last character from date string after format.
dateformat = {{( string | limitTo: 10 ).trim()}}